# LO Calc: dragging complements cell not as expected

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I created in table1 a list of persons, one person per row : in A1 Max, in A2 Tom and in A3 Georg. In table2 I want align the persons in columns. I wrote in table2 in cell B1

```
=table1.A1
```

an in C1

```
=table1.A2
```

I marked both and dragged to the right. In cell D1 now appears

```
 table1.C4
```

but I liked to have

```
=table1.A3
```

Comment: Add images and format text better. Show us your effort.

Comment: I followed the steps you described, and `=table1.C1` appears in cell D1, not `table1.D4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a formula, set `table2.B1` to:

```
=INDIRECT("table1.A"&COLUMN()-1)
```

Then drag the formula to D1, which now shows `Georg`.  For documentation, see [INDIRECT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDIRECT) and [COLUMN](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#COLUMN).

Alternatively, transpose the data by copying and pasting special, described in https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Rotating_Tables_Transposing.